# set sql database name with an alphanumeric phrase - C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, mdf

I'm trying to make a simple thing but it has become difficult as I do not understand why I proves a mistake like that, I'll explain , I would like to set the database name as well : "FD65F10A-0F6F-487C-A5E4-18A783DC18AE" (PID variable)

But if I leave this , I get this error :

[image]

the problem seems to be the hyphen , because if I remove it and septum so : FD65F10A0F6F487CA5E418A783DC18AE everything works , saves me the db and I can go way on the debug..Come I can use the hyphen ? you need to use it , I have to find a solution . Thank you

Comment: Try surrounding the DB name with `[` and `]`

Comment: Why downvoting him? isn't that a good question? comeon

Comment: where i set [and] ? sorry my i'm new on sql server. Thanks

Comment: `"CREATE DATABASE [" + PID + "] ...`

Comment: ah ok, i'have try it but don't work

Comment: Can you update with exactly what you tried?

Comment: @Mr.Developer did I complain something?

Comment: I have to set the name of a database dynamically created with the "-" character , for example: this-is- my-name-of-db.mdf . The problem is that I do not accept the "- " . I found nothing in the literature to say that the " - " is forbidden in the naming to db .

Comment: Have you tried doing it with quotes surrounding?

Comment: @believeme 
In fact, I gave you reason , maybe my bad English I explained badly

Comment: yes i try with surrounding

Comment: Side note - you should just do `throw;` instead of `throw ex;` - otherwise you may lose some of the exception information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only is the database name failing, but also your `LOG ON` line.

Put square brackets around the database name and around the log name:

```
"CREATE DATABASE [" + PID + "] ..."
...
"LOG ON (NAME = [" + PID + "Log_Log] ..."
```

Comment: how could I not have thought of that before ? ! through works

Answer (score 0):

You can use  delimited characters for naming.

```
String str = "CREATE DATABASE '" + PID + "' ON PRIMARY "........
```

Noting the single quotes in the string on either side of the PID variable.

Comment: Does not work I had already tried before to the question , I think , at this time, the use of " - " is not allowed in the file name.

Comment: @Mr.Developer Could you use an underscore instead maybe?

Comment: underscore works, but would hyphenated the name of the file ... so I guess the last resort is to do the replace .

Comment: Yea just change the string variable with PID = PID.Replace("-", "_") and that will allow it.

Comment: it is clear know how you program , are only new sql server, sql lite you can name as you like, for what I opened the question . Thanks anyway